# How to convert multiple column values to a single column having multiple rows in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

I am unable to convert multiple columns into a single column keeping remaining columns intact

I have the following table `table1`

```
 Name        Category1         Category2        Category3   .....     Tag
=======     ===========       ===========      ===========          ========
 Jason         5                  6                 4                senior
 Walter        3                  7                 10               junior
   .
   .
   .
```

How do I merge all categories into a single column called category_mix?

Basically, I want to use the data from `table1` to populate another table, `table2` such that it gets populated in this manner

```
 Name            category_mix        Tag
=======         ==============     =======
Jason                5              senior
Jason                6              senior
Jason                4              senior
Walter               3              junior
Walter               7              junior
Walter               10             junior
```

How do I go about doing this in Postgres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `values` clause to achieve the unpivot:

```
select t.name, c.category_mix, t.tag
from table1 t
   cross join lateral ( 
       values (category1), (category2), (category3)
   ) as c(category_mix);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5351d63f466079891d85529cd272a811)

Comment: Is this syntax correct? I keep getting an error saying "category1 does not exist. Hint: there is a column named category1 in t but it cannot be referenced in this part of the query"

Comment: @Vinay: sorry, forgot the `lateral`